# Outlook reminders gone missing on Citrix client (works in cached mode)

Tags: citrix, outlook-2010

**Setup**
3 ESXi 5.1 hosts, 4 virtual XENAPP servers (3 in production, 1 test server), 300 users (50 PC's, the rest is on clients), Exchange 2010

**Problem**
One Citrix user's Outlook suddenly won't show reminders anymore. Everybody elses works just fine.

So far I tried
1) In outlook: Show -> Reminders -> 0 reminders (this is the problem). 
2) In outlook: Checked (and checked again) that reminders are set correctly. Files -> Settings -> Advanced -> reminders -> Show reminders -> checkboxed 
3) In outlook: Changed setting to cached mode. Works, resetting back to none-cached mode. No go.
4) Logged him off, deleted his Citrix profile (this kinda fix most), logged him in again, no luck.

I hoped that reversing cached mode in step 3 would make outlook sync everything back to the exchange server. Do I misunderstand something here? Also, I've been reading about 'outlook /cleanreminders' and 'outlook /resetfolders' could do the trick. Will these commands also apply to a Citrix clients? (and how to do it - im quite new to Citrix).

Im not sure why, but I'm having a hunch that its not so Citrix related, but more outlook/exhange related. But again, im new to Citrix.

Any thougts and suggestions are highly appriciated. Thank you.
-Rasmus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the FAQ it seems to be okay to answer your own question. It's already in the commentary above, but to close it off, here goes:

The problem was with outlook, not with Citrix. As stated above, I deleted all notifications older that one month (users best guess to when the problem accured), and bingo - the remaining reminders showed up as supposed to.

I wish I could give more details into whether it was syncronization error og what else, but this is all I got.

Answer (score 0):

Take Outlook out of cached mode and then delete the OST file. Then put Outlook back in cached mode and see if that fixes the problem.

/resetfolders isn't likely to do anything because that restores missing default folders, which is not your problem.

/cleanreminders might work but I would follow my first suggestion first. It sounds like there's a problem with the OST file.

Comment: Thanks, I tried as your suggested, but unfortunately no luck. There is a difference though. When I make a new entry in the users calender, outlook flashes the reminder window for a second, with all the reminders there, and then its gone again.

Comment: Yepekayaa - it works! I deleted all notifications more than one month old. Thats it - apperantly one of them blocked the rest.